Adding a diagram to a chart
I would like to be able to have this type of graph:

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage[all]{chemmacros}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            xmin=-10,xmax=400,
            ymin=-2,ymax=50.1,    % <<<
            samples = 100,
            no markers,
            axis x line=bottom,axis y line = left,
            ylabel={$E_p (\unit{\kJ\per\mol})$},
            xlabel={$\theta (\unit{\degree})$},
            xtick={0,60,120,180,240,300,360},
            ytick=\empty,
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=blue] expression[domain=0:360,samples=100]{5*cos(3*x)+25};

        \end{axis}
         \end{tikzpicture}%
\newman(0){}
\newman(62){}
\newman(120){}
\newman(180){}
\newman(240){}
\newman(300){}
\end{document}


Basically you just need to add nodes at the given coordinates.  The only tricky bit is that the images are centered and \newman is not always symmetrical (vertically).
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage[all]{chemmacros}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            %xmin=-10,xmax=420,
            ymin=-2,ymax=55,    % <<<
            samples = 100,
            no markers,
            axis x line=bottom,axis y line = left,
            ylabel={$E_p (\unit{\kJ\per\mol})$},
            xlabel={$\theta (\unit{\degree})$},
            xtick={0,60,120,180,240,300,360,420},
            ytick=\empty,
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=blue] expression[domain=0:420,samples=100]{5*cos(3*x)+25};
            \node at (120,42) {\newman(120){}};
            \node at (240,42) {\newman(240){}};
            \node at (360,42) {\newman(360){}};
            \node at (60,10) {\newman(60){}};
            \node at (180,10) {\newman(180){}};
            \node at (300,10) {\newman(300){}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}


